# PERMITIR QUE UN INPUT EN PYTHON ACEPTE TANTO INT COMO FLOAT COMO RESPUESTA POSIBLE

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código que busca promediar la nota de 2 exámenes. No obstante, me di cuenta que el valor que se puede ingresar por consola no necesariamente debe ser un entero, ya que puede ser un float, como 9.5. pero si la persona ingresa un float por consola me da error el codigo.

¿como tengo que hacer para que mi codigo acepte tanto el float como el int como respuestas validas?

```
Nota1 = int(input("introduzca la nota del primer examen: "))
Promedio1 = int(input("introduzca el % del examen para la nota final: "))
Nota2 = int(input("introduzca la nota del segundo examen: "))
Promedio2 = int(input("introduzca el % del examen para la nota final: "))

Promedios = Promedio1 + Promedio2

Nota_Final = (Nota1*Promedio1 + Nota2*Promedio2)/Promedios
print(f"La nota final promediada es: {Nota_Final}")
```

Comment: Cambia los `int(input(...` por `float(input(...`. Esto convertirá las cadenas devueltas por input en flotantes (claro, siempre que sea posible. Si no es posible, ocurrirá un error)

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, ya lo pude solucionar!!!

Answer (score 0):

Es posible crear una función estilo pedir_numero, que va a insistir hasta que el tipo de input sea el correcto, aprovechándonos del error que levanta python cuando se usa float en un input no válido.

La función

```
num = float(input(mensaje))
```

Acepta un input (que siempre es string) y lo convierte a punto flotante (float). El asunto es que si utilizas el formato de coma europeo y sudamericano (ej: 2,5 - 9,99) obtendrás un error, lo mismo que si tienes letras o demás.

Entonces podemos pedirle al usuario que ingrese de manera insistente un número válido hasta que lo haga, usando un loop infinito que sólo se detenga mediante un break cuando esa conversión no devuelva el error.

Aprovecharía para hacerlo como una función y reutilizarlo fácilmente

El código quedaría algo así:

```
def pedir_numero(mensaje):
    while True:
        try:
            num = float(input(mensaje))
        except ValueError:
            print("Debe ingresar un número")
            continue
        else:
            break
    return num

Nota1 = pedir_numero("introduzca la nota del primer examen: ")
Promedio1 = pedir_numero("introduzca el % del examen para la nota final: ")
Nota2 = pedir_numero("introduzca la nota del segundo examen: ")
Promedio2 = pedir_numero("introduzca el % del examen para la nota final: ")

Promedios = Promedio1 + Promedio2

Nota_Final = (Nota1*Promedio1 + Nota2*Promedio2)/Promedios
print(f"La nota final promediada es: {Nota_Final}")
```

Comment: En mi opinión estaría bueno que expliques como esta respuesta resuelve el pedido del OP.

Comment: Gracias por la observación Dante, respuesta editada.

Comment: De nada Marcelo c:

Answer (score 0):

ejemplo:

nombre = input("ingrese tu nombre completo")

edad = input("ingrese tu edad completa")

solucion = ("mi nombre es %s, y mi edad es %d" % (nombre, edad))

#el %s Exige un string, y el %d un integer. y el % format